# Convert NSString to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I got below response in `NSString` and I want to convert it into `NSMutableDictionary`

```
{
  "dictionary": [
    {
      "title": "أذكار الاستيقاظ من النوم",
      "id": "1",
      "prod_image": [
       {
          "title_des": "الحَمْدُ لله الذِي أحْيَانا بَعْدَ مَا أمَاتَنَا وإلَيْهِ النَشُور"
       },
       {
          "title_des": "الحَمْدُ لله الذِي عَافَانِي في جَسَدِي ورَدَّ عَلَيَّ رُوحِي، وأَذِنَ لي بِذِكْرهِ"
       },
       {
          "title_des": "قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم \"مَنْ تَعَارَ مِنَ اللَّيْل*  فقال حين يستيقظ :\"لا إلَهَ إلاَّ الله وحْدَهُ لا شَرِيكَ لَهُ، لَهُ المُلْكُ ولَهُ الحَمْدُ وهُوَ على كلِّ شيءٍ قَدير،سُبْحانَ الله والحَمْدُ لله  ولا إله إلا الله والله أكبر ولا حَولَ ولا قُوةَ إلا بالله العلي العظيم \" ثم دعا: \" اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لي، غُفِرَ له \"، قال الوليد: أو قال: \" دعا استُجيبَ لهُ، فإن قام فتوضأَ ثمصَلّى قُبِلَتْ صَلاتُهُ "
       },
       {
          "title_des": "إِنَّ فِي خَلْقِ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالأَرْضِ وَاخْتِلاَفِ اللَّيْلِ وَالنَّهَارِ لآيَاتٍ لِّأُوْلِي الألْبَابِ *الَّذِينَ يَذْكُرُونَ اللّهَ قِيَاماً وَقُعُوداً وَعَلَىَ جُنُوبِهِمْ وَيَتَفَكَّرُونَ فِي خَلْقِ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالأَرْضِ رَبَّنَا مَا خَلَقْتَ هَذا بَاطِلاً سُبْحَانَكَ فَقِنَا عَذَابَ النَّارِ*رَبَّنَا إِنَّكَ مَن تُدْخِلِ النَّارَ فَقَدْ أَخْزَيْتَهُ وَمَا لِلظَّالِمِينَ مِنْ أَنصَارٍ *رَّبَّنَا إِنَّنَا سَمِعْنَا مُنَادِياً يُنَادِي لِلإِيمَانِ أَنْ آمِنُواْ بِرَبِّكُمْ فَآمَنَّا رَبَّنَا فَاغْفِرْ لَنَا ذُنُوبَنَا وَكَفِّرْ عَنَّا سَيِّئَاتِنَا وَتَوَفَّنَا مَعَ الأبْرَارِ * رَبَّنَا وَآتِنَا مَا وَعَدتَّنَا عَلَى رُسُلِكَ وَلاَ تُخْزِنَا يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ إِنَّكَ لاَ تُخْلِفُ الْمِيعَادَ *فَاسْتَجَابَ لَهُمْ رَبُّهُمْ أَنِّي لاَ أُضِيعُ عَمَلَ عَامِلٍ مِّنكُم مِّن ذَكَرٍ أَوْ أُنثَى بَعْضُكُم مِّن بَعْضٍ فَالَّذِينَ هَاجَرُواْ وَأُخْرِجُواْ مِن دِيَارِهِمْ وَأُوذُواْ فِي سَبِيلِي وَقَاتَلُواْ وَقُتِلُواْ لأُكَفِّرَنَّ عَنْهُمْ سَيِّئَاتِهِمْ وَلأُدْخِلَنَّهُمْ جَنَّاتٍ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا الأَنْهَارُ ثَوَاباً مِّن عِندِ اللّهِ وَاللّهُ عِندَهُ حُسْنُ الثَّوَابِ *لاَ يَغُرَّنَّكَ تَقَلُّبُ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُواْ فِي الْبِلاَدِ *مَتَاعٌ قَلِيلٌ ثُمَّ مَأْوَاهُمْ جَهَنَّمُ وَبِئْسَ الْمِهَادُ *لَكِنِ الَّذِينَ اتَّقَوْاْ رَبَّهُمْ لَهُمْ جَنَّاتٌ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا الأَنْهَارُ خَالِدِينَ فِيهَا نُزُلاً مِّنْ عِندِ اللّهِ وَمَا عِندَ اللّهِ خَيْرٌ لِّلأَبْرَارِ * وَإِنَّ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ لَمَن يُؤْمِنُ بِاللّهِ وَمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْكُمْ وَمَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْهِمْ خَاشِعِينَ لِلّهِ لاَ يَشْتَرُونَ بِآيَاتِ اللّهِ ثَمَناً قَلِيلاً أُوْلَـئِكَ لَهُمْ أَجْرُهُمْ عِندَ رَبِّهِمْ إِنَّ اللّهَ سَرِيعُ الْحِسَابِ *يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُواْ اصْبِرُواْ وَصَابِرُواْ وَرَابِطُواْ وَاتَّقُواْ اللّهَ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ"
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**NSDictionary *myDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];** // use this code for convert Convert NSString to NSDictionary

After convert NSString to NSDictionary i got responce like this:

```
{
   dictionary =     (
            {
            id = 1;
            "prod_image" =             (
                            {
                "title_des" = "\U0627\U0644\U062d\U064e\U0645\U0652\U062f\U064f \U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0627\U0644\U0630\U0650\U064a \U0623\U062d\U0652\U064a\U064e\U0627\U0646\U0627 \U0628\U064e\U0639\U0652\U062f\U064e \U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0623\U0645\U064e\U0627\U062a\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0648\U0625\U0644\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0647\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0646\U064e\U0634\U064f\U0648\U0631";
            },
                            {
                "title_des" = "\U0627\U0644\U062d\U064e\U0645\U0652\U062f\U064f \U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0627\U0644\U0630\U0650\U064a \U0639\U064e\U0627\U0641\U064e\U0627\U0646\U0650\U064a \U0641\U064a \U062c\U064e\U0633\U064e\U062f\U0650\U064a \U0648\U0631\U064e\U062f\U0651\U064e \U0639\U064e\U0644\U064e\U064a\U0651\U064e \U0631\U064f\U0648\U062d\U0650\U064a\U060c \U0648\U0623\U064e\U0630\U0650\U0646\U064e \U0644\U064a \U0628\U0650\U0630\U0650\U0643\U0652\U0631\U0647\U0650";
            },
                            {
                "title_des" = "\U0642\U0627\U0644 \U0631\U0633\U0648\U0644 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0635\U0644\U0649 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0639\U0644\U064a\U0647 \U0648\U0633\U0644\U0645 \"\U0645\U064e\U0646\U0652 \U062a\U064e\U0639\U064e\U0627\U0631\U064e \U0645\U0650\U0646\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0644*  \U0641\U0642\U0627\U0644 \U062d\U064a\U0646 \U064a\U0633\U062a\U064a\U0642\U0638 :\"\U0644\U0627 \U0625\U0644\U064e\U0647\U064e \U0625\U0644\U0627\U0651\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0648\U062d\U0652\U062f\U064e\U0647\U064f \U0644\U0627 \U0634\U064e\U0631\U0650\U064a\U0643\U064e \U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f\U060c \U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f \U0627\U0644\U0645\U064f\U0644\U0652\U0643\U064f \U0648\U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f \U0627\U0644\U062d\U064e\U0645\U0652\U062f\U064f \U0648\U0647\U064f\U0648\U064e \U0639\U0644\U0649 \U0643\U0644\U0651\U0650 \U0634\U064a\U0621\U064d \U0642\U064e\U062f\U064a\U0631\U060c\U0633\U064f\U0628\U0652\U062d\U0627\U0646\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0648\U0627\U0644\U062d\U064e\U0645\U0652\U062f\U064f \U0644\U0644\U0647  \U0648\U0644\U0627 \U0625\U0644\U0647 \U0625\U0644\U0627 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0648\U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0623\U0643\U0628\U0631 \U0648\U0644\U0627 \U062d\U064e\U0648\U0644\U064e \U0648\U0644\U0627 \U0642\U064f\U0648\U0629\U064e \U0625\U0644\U0627 \U0628\U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0627\U0644\U0639\U0644\U064a \U0627\U0644\U0639\U0638\U064a\U0645 \" \U062b\U0645 \U062f\U0639\U0627: \" \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0651\U064e \U0627\U063a\U0652\U0641\U0650\U0631\U0652 \U0644\U064a\U060c \U063a\U064f\U0641\U0650\U0631\U064e \U0644\U0647 \"\U060c \U0642\U0627\U0644 \U0627\U0644\U0648\U0644\U064a\U062f: \U0623\U0648 \U0642\U0627\U0644: \" \U062f\U0639\U0627 \U0627\U0633\U062a\U064f\U062c\U064a\U0628\U064e \U0644\U0647\U064f\U060c \U0641\U0625\U0646 \U0642\U0627\U0645 \U0641\U062a\U0648\U0636\U0623\U064e \U062b\U0645\U0635\U064e\U0644\U0651\U0649 \U0642\U064f\U0628\U0650\U0644\U064e\U062a\U0652 \U0635\U064e\U0644\U0627\U062a\U064f\U0647\U064f ";
            },
                            {
                "title_des" = "\U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e \U0641\U0650\U064a \U062e\U064e\U0644\U0652\U0642\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0633\U0651\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627\U0648\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0623\U064e\U0631\U0652\U0636\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U062e\U0652\U062a\U0650\U0644\U0627\U064e\U0641\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0644\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0647\U064e\U0627\U0631\U0650 \U0644\U0622\U064a\U064e\U0627\U062a\U064d \U0644\U0651\U0650\U0623\U064f\U0648\U0652\U0644\U0650\U064a \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0644\U0652\U0628\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650 *\U0627\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0630\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U064a\U064e\U0630\U0652\U0643\U064f\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0646\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U064e \U0642\U0650\U064a\U064e\U0627\U0645\U0627\U064b \U0648\U064e\U0642\U064f\U0639\U064f\U0648\U062f\U0627\U064b \U0648\U064e\U0639\U064e\U0644\U064e\U0649\U064e \U062c\U064f\U0646\U064f\U0648\U0628\U0650\U0647\U0650\U0645\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U064a\U064e\U062a\U064e\U0641\U064e\U0643\U0651\U064e\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0646\U064e \U0641\U0650\U064a \U062e\U064e\U0644\U0652\U0642\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0633\U0651\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627\U0648\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0623\U064e\U0631\U0652\U0636\U0650 \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0645\U064e\U0627 \U062e\U064e\U0644\U064e\U0642\U0652\U062a\U064e \U0647\U064e\U0630\U0627 \U0628\U064e\U0627\U0637\U0650\U0644\U0627\U064b \U0633\U064f\U0628\U0652\U062d\U064e\U0627\U0646\U064e\U0643\U064e \U0641\U064e\U0642\U0650\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0639\U064e\U0630\U064e\U0627\U0628\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627\U0631\U0650*\U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0643\U064e \U0645\U064e\U0646 \U062a\U064f\U062f\U0652\U062e\U0650\U0644\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627\U0631\U064e \U0641\U064e\U0642\U064e\U062f\U0652 \U0623\U064e\U062e\U0652\U0632\U064e\U064a\U0652\U062a\U064e\U0647\U064f \U0648\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0644\U0650\U0644\U0638\U0651\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0650\U0645\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0645\U0650\U0646\U0652 \U0623\U064e\U0646\U0635\U064e\U0627\U0631\U064d *\U0631\U0651\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0633\U064e\U0645\U0650\U0639\U0652\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0645\U064f\U0646\U064e\U0627\U062f\U0650\U064a\U0627\U064b \U064a\U064f\U0646\U064e\U0627\U062f\U0650\U064a \U0644\U0650\U0644\U0625\U0650\U064a\U0645\U064e\U0627\U0646\U0650 \U0623\U064e\U0646\U0652 \U0622\U0645\U0650\U0646\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0628\U0650\U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U0650\U0643\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0641\U064e\U0622\U0645\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627 \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0641\U064e\U0627\U063a\U0652\U0641\U0650\U0631\U0652 \U0644\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0630\U064f\U0646\U064f\U0648\U0628\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0648\U064e\U0643\U064e\U0641\U0651\U0650\U0631\U0652 \U0639\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627 \U0633\U064e\U064a\U0651\U0650\U0626\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0650\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0648\U064e\U062a\U064e\U0648\U064e\U0641\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0645\U064e\U0639\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0623\U0628\U0652\U0631\U064e\U0627\U0631\U0650 * \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0648\U064e\U0622\U062a\U0650\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0648\U064e\U0639\U064e\U062f\U062a\U0651\U064e\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U0639\U064e\U0644\U064e\U0649 \U0631\U064f\U0633\U064f\U0644\U0650\U0643\U064e \U0648\U064e\U0644\U0627\U064e \U062a\U064f\U062e\U0652\U0632\U0650\U0646\U064e\U0627 \U064a\U064e\U0648\U0652\U0645\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0652\U0642\U0650\U064a\U064e\U0627\U0645\U064e\U0629\U0650 \U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0643\U064e \U0644\U0627\U064e \U062a\U064f\U062e\U0652\U0644\U0650\U0641\U064f \U0627\U0644\U0652\U0645\U0650\U064a\U0639\U064e\U0627\U062f\U064e *\U0641\U064e\U0627\U0633\U0652\U062a\U064e\U062c\U064e\U0627\U0628\U064e \U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064f\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0623\U064e\U0646\U0651\U0650\U064a \U0644\U0627\U064e \U0623\U064f\U0636\U0650\U064a\U0639\U064f \U0639\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0644\U064e \U0639\U064e\U0627\U0645\U0650\U0644\U064d \U0645\U0651\U0650\U0646\U0643\U064f\U0645 \U0645\U0651\U0650\U0646 \U0630\U064e\U0643\U064e\U0631\U064d \U0623\U064e\U0648\U0652 \U0623\U064f\U0646\U062b\U064e\U0649 \U0628\U064e\U0639\U0652\U0636\U064f\U0643\U064f\U0645 \U0645\U0651\U0650\U0646 \U0628\U064e\U0639\U0652\U0636\U064d \U0641\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0630\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0647\U064e\U0627\U062c\U064e\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0623\U064f\U062e\U0652\U0631\U0650\U062c\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0645\U0650\U0646 \U062f\U0650\U064a\U064e\U0627\U0631\U0650\U0647\U0650\U0645\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0623\U064f\U0648\U0630\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0641\U0650\U064a \U0633\U064e\U0628\U0650\U064a\U0644\U0650\U064a \U0648\U064e\U0642\U064e\U0627\U062a\U064e\U0644\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0642\U064f\U062a\U0650\U0644\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0644\U0623\U064f\U0643\U064e\U0641\U0651\U0650\U0631\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e \U0639\U064e\U0646\U0652\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0633\U064e\U064a\U0651\U0650\U0626\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0650\U0647\U0650\U0645\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0644\U0623\U064f\U062f\U0652\U062e\U0650\U0644\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U062c\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627\U062a\U064d \U062a\U064e\U062c\U0652\U0631\U0650\U064a \U0645\U0650\U0646 \U062a\U064e\U062d\U0652\U062a\U0650\U0647\U064e\U0627 \U0627\U0644\U0623\U064e\U0646\U0652\U0647\U064e\U0627\U0631\U064f \U062b\U064e\U0648\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0627\U064b \U0645\U0651\U0650\U0646 \U0639\U0650\U0646\U062f\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U064f \U0639\U0650\U0646\U062f\U064e\U0647\U064f \U062d\U064f\U0633\U0652\U0646\U064f \U0627\U0644\U062b\U0651\U064e\U0648\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650 *\U0644\U0627\U064e \U064a\U064e\U063a\U064f\U0631\U0651\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0643\U064e \U062a\U064e\U0642\U064e\U0644\U0651\U064f\U0628\U064f \U0627\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0630\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0643\U064e\U0641\U064e\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0641\U0650\U064a \U0627\U0644\U0652\U0628\U0650\U0644\U0627\U064e\U062f\U0650 *\U0645\U064e\U062a\U064e\U0627\U0639\U064c \U0642\U064e\U0644\U0650\U064a\U0644\U064c \U062b\U064f\U0645\U0651\U064e \U0645\U064e\U0623\U0652\U0648\U064e\U0627\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U062c\U064e\U0647\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0645\U064f \U0648\U064e\U0628\U0650\U0626\U0652\U0633\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0652\U0645\U0650\U0647\U064e\U0627\U062f\U064f *\U0644\U064e\U0643\U0650\U0646\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0630\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0627\U062a\U0651\U064e\U0642\U064e\U0648\U0652\U0627\U0652 \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U062c\U064e\U0646\U0651\U064e\U0627\U062a\U064c \U062a\U064e\U062c\U0652\U0631\U0650\U064a \U0645\U0650\U0646 \U062a\U064e\U062d\U0652\U062a\U0650\U0647\U064e\U0627 \U0627\U0644\U0623\U064e\U0646\U0652\U0647\U064e\U0627\U0631\U064f \U062e\U064e\U0627\U0644\U0650\U062f\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0641\U0650\U064a\U0647\U064e\U0627 \U0646\U064f\U0632\U064f\U0644\U0627\U064b \U0645\U0651\U0650\U0646\U0652 \U0639\U0650\U0646\U062f\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0639\U0650\U0646\U062f\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U062e\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0631\U064c \U0644\U0651\U0650\U0644\U0623\U064e\U0628\U0652\U0631\U064e\U0627\U0631\U0650 * \U0648\U064e\U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e \U0645\U0650\U0646\U0652 \U0623\U064e\U0647\U0652\U0644\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0652\U0643\U0650\U062a\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650 \U0644\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0646 \U064a\U064f\U0624\U0652\U0645\U0650\U0646\U064f \U0628\U0650\U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U0648\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0623\U064f\U0646\U0632\U0650\U0644\U064e \U0625\U0650\U0644\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0643\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0627 \U0623\U064f\U0646\U0632\U0650\U0644\U064e \U0625\U0650\U0644\U064e\U064a\U0652\U0647\U0650\U0645\U0652 \U062e\U064e\U0627\U0634\U0650\U0639\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0644\U0650\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U0644\U0627\U064e \U064a\U064e\U0634\U0652\U062a\U064e\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0646\U064e \U0628\U0650\U0622\U064a\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0650 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U0650 \U062b\U064e\U0645\U064e\U0646\U0627\U064b \U0642\U064e\U0644\U0650\U064a\U0644\U0627\U064b \U0623\U064f\U0648\U0652\U0644\U064e\U0640\U0626\U0650\U0643\U064e \U0644\U064e\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0623\U064e\U062c\U0652\U0631\U064f\U0647\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U0639\U0650\U0646\U062f\U064e \U0631\U064e\U0628\U0651\U0650\U0647\U0650\U0645\U0652 \U0625\U0650\U0646\U0651\U064e \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U064e \U0633\U064e\U0631\U0650\U064a\U0639\U064f \U0627\U0644\U0652\U062d\U0650\U0633\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650 *\U064a\U064e\U0627 \U0623\U064e\U064a\U0651\U064f\U0647\U064e\U0627 \U0627\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0630\U0650\U064a\U0646\U064e \U0622\U0645\U064e\U0646\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0627\U0635\U0652\U0628\U0650\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0635\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650\U0631\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0631\U064e\U0627\U0628\U0650\U0637\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0648\U064e\U0627\U062a\U0651\U064e\U0642\U064f\U0648\U0627\U0652 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0651\U0647\U064e \U0644\U064e\U0639\U064e\U0644\U0651\U064e\U0643\U064f\U0645\U0652 \U062a\U064f\U0641\U0652\U0644\U0650\U062d\U064f\U0648\U0646\U064e";
            }
        );
        title = "\U0623\U0630\U0643\U0627\U0631 \U0627\U0644\U0627\U0633\U062a\U064a\U0642\U0627\U0638 \U0645\U0646 \U0627\U0644\U0646\U0648\U0645";
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to read direct data from file which is in the project.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Look for JSON Serialization?

Comment: How are you converting to Dictionary? Code?

Comment: What you have initially is JSON source.  The second listing is a dump of the resulting dictionary after "deserialization".  It's a NSDictionary much like any other.  It contains one entry named "dictionary", which is an NSArray containing one element which contains yet another NSDictinary which contains as one of its elements an NSArray containing 4 NSDictionary objects.  You've confused things a bit in the copy/paste by appending the end of the JSON source vs the end of the NSDictionary dump in the last few lines.

Comment: (Hint, `[]` is JSON "array", `()` is NSArray, `{}` is JSON "object" or NSDictionary.  See json.org for info on the JSON syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary *myDictionary = [responseString JSONValue]; It's giving you correct Dictionary and Arrays.

e.g

```
[[myDictionary objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"prod_image"];
```

give you the "title_des". If you want to get the First "title_des" then You can do something Like..

```
[[[[myDictionary objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"prod_image"]objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"title_des"];
```

When you print the "title_des" it will give you right result. But When you NSLOg the result it will not give you Correct Arabic.

You have to use the NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Let me know If you know something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON string so you can load it inside a NSDictionary using:

```
NSData *data = [self.json dataUsingEncoding:<encoding for arabian character>];
NSDictionary *dicSignature = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Don't know about the encoding to use here, but for example, latin character would use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: <encoding for arabian character> means ?

Comment: I don't know what encoding is used for arabians character. Is it ASCII, is it UTF8 ? According to this the answer would be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` or `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `JSON` string as response. To convert it into `NSMutableDictionary`, you have to use 
`NSJSONSerialization` or any other way to convert it.
 Try this:-

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourResponse options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: The lower listing is already an NSDictionary (other than the miscopied part at the bottom).